# Identify subsets containing only repeats of an expression

Tags: r

I have a dataset like so:

```
 df<-data.frame(x=c("A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B", 
                   "C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),  
                y= as.factor(c(rep("Eoissp2",4),rep("Eoissp1",5),"Eoissp1","Eoisp4","Automerissp1","Automerissp2","Acharias",rep("Eoissp2",3),rep("Eoissp1",2))))
```

I want to identify, for each subset of `x`, the corresponding levels in `y` that are entirely duplicates containing the expression `Eois`. Therefore, `A` , `B`, and `D` will be returned in a vector because every level of  `A` , `B`, and `D` contains the expression `Eois` , while level `C` consists of various unique levels (e.g. Eois, Automeris and Acharias). For this example the output would be:

```
   output<- c("A", "B", "D")
```

Comment: `names(which(with(unique(df),by(x,x,length)==1)))`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated my post because I do not think I was being clear. Are you able to take a look at my comments to @mysteRious. Thank you

Comment: `unique(as.character(df[duplicated(df),"x"]))`

Comment: @Onyambu Your solution is very crisp and short but it would have worked on original post from OP.

Comment: I don't know why he keeps changing the data yet the logic remains the same

Comment: He edited the question again.

Comment: @Danielle the function I gave you does solve your problem.

Comment: Apologies for the edits, but I am trying to get to the bottom of this. Are you sure logic remains the same with my edits? It is hard to find my error in logic any explanation is appreciated. Good learning experience and I appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: I hope that was last updates:-). Have a look at answer. You can work out slight modifications in logic on your own. Isnt it? The basic logic will remain same which was decided in your original post itself.

Comment: run the code and you will still get the same results. because you need any that is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using new df:

```
> df %>% filter(str_detect(y,"Eois")) %>% group_by(x) %>% distinct(y) %>% 
    count() %>% filter(n==1) %>% select(x)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
# Groups:   x [2]
  x    
  <fct>
1 A    
2 B
```

(Answer below uses the original df posted by the question author.)

Using the pipe function in `magrittr` & functions from `dplyr`:

```
> df %>% group_by(x) %>% distinct(y)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   x [3]
  x     y      
  <fct> <fct>  
1 A     plant1a
2 B     plant1b
3 C     plant1a
4 C     plant2a
5 C     plant3a
6 C     plant4a 
7 C     plant5a
```

Then you can roll up the results like this:

```
> results <- df %>% group_by(x) %>% distinct(y) %>% 
    count() %>% filter(n==1) %>% select(x)
> results
# A tibble: 2 x 1
# Groups:   x [2]
  x    
  <fct>
1 A    
2 B
```

If you know your original data frame is always going to come with the x's in order, you can drop the `group_by` part.

Comment: I appreciate you help. I do not think I was clear in my original post about the expression. It is important I use part of the expression to ID subsets where each level contains `Eois` in some capacity. Are you able to update your post? Thank you for your time. I was thinking "grepl" would need to be used in some capacity.

Comment: So do you want to ignore any line that does not have "Eois" in it?

Comment: Any subset of x that does not have the expression `Eois` in all levels  of y. For example, I would ignore `C`. While it has two levels of `y` with the expression `Eois`, it has other levels that do not contain that expression. Essentially, I am trying to go through a massive dataset and filter out months (x) where the only caterpillar species (y) collected in that month was from a single  genus `Eois`. Thanks for giving this a shot

Comment: Check out what I just edited in and see if this works :)

Comment: I apologize for the many edits, Your solution was not working on my data and I believe it may be because in some cases (as in level D all levels contain `Eois` but they are different `Eois` types. Again,  I apologize for the many changes.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` based solution could be as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>%
  filter(grepl("Eoiss", y)) %>%
  mutate(y = sub("\\d+", "", y)) %>%
  filter(n() >1 & length(unique(y)) == 1) %>%
  select(x) %>% unique(.)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
# Groups: x [3]
#  x     
#  <fctr>
#1 A     
#2 B     
#3 D
```

**Data**

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B", 
                   "C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),  
               y= as.factor(c(rep("Eoissp2",4),
      rep("Eoissp1",5),"Eoissp1","Eoisp4","Automerissp1","Automerissp2",
      "Acharias",rep("Eoissp2",3),rep("Eoissp1",2))))
```